# How to find the key of a hash whose value has the most elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, max

I'm using Ruby 2.4.

I have a hash whose key is a number and whose value is an array of elements.  How do I find the key in the hash with the value that has the most elements?  I know that if my value were a single number I could do this:

```
my_hash.max_by { |k, v| v }
```

But since the value is an array, I'm not sure how to tell the above to use the number of elements in the array as what should be maxed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) is the correct method :

```
my_hash = { a: [1, 2], b: [1, 2, 3], c: [5] }

key, longest_array = my_hash.max_by{ |k, array| array.size }

p key
#=> :b

p longest_array
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

You just need to specify on which object the comparison should be. In this case, the size of the array value.

You might need to add some checks first : this will only work if all the hash values respond to `:size`.

Comment: Worth noting the `.first` call is necessary because `max_by` returns a key/value pair for hashes.

Comment: Thanks. I usually write code ASAP and edit the answer for more information. ;)

Comment: Yep! Just adding some clarification since that might seem awfully mysterious to the uninitiated.

Comment: Removed the paragraph that talked about `first` since that is not used in your code anymore. Hope that is okay, feel free to revert.

Comment: I'm not sure. Another user could come and comment that `longest_array` is unneeded here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
my_hash.map {|k, v| [k, v.count]}.max_by {|k, v| v}.first
```

The first map will return an array of two elements arrays. For each of them, the first element is the key and the second is the number of elements of the corresponding array. Then it uses `max_by` to return the two element array with the maximum number of elements. Finally, the `first` method returns the key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
my_hash = {1=>[2, 1, 3, 4], 2=>[1, 2], 3=>[1, 4, 6]}
```

If that's the case, you can get the key for the largest array like this:

```
my_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.count}.first
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between using "count" or using "size," as what Eric suggests?

Comment: According to : http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/ `count` is slower for some `Enumerable`s, but should be the same as `size` or `length` for arrays